# Cyrillic characters with tapestry request

Tags: java, utf-8, request, tapestry

I'm using the autocomplete component of textfield 'senderReceiverName' and when it is filled, on the action on blur I want to fill the 'senderReceiverAddress'

So the problem is, when I put in Textfield 'senderReceiverName' Cyrillic characters the request.getParameter("param"); is returning numbers, for Latin characters is working fine.

Here is the .tml

```
<t:Zone t:id="srZone5" id="srZone5">
    <t:TextField t:id="senderReceiverName" t:value="currentDoc?.senderReceiverName"
        t:validate="required" t:mixins="autocomplete,ZoneUpdater" t:disabled="${editable}" t:clientEvent="blur" t:event="senderReceiverChanged"
        style="width:500px;" t:zone="srZone10" />
</t:Zone>

<t:Zone t:id="srZone10" id="srZone10">
    <t:TextArea t:id="senderReceiverAddress"
        t:value="currentDoc?.senderReceiverAddress" t:disabled="true"
        style="width:500px;" />
</t:Zone>
```

And here is the java class

```
@Inject
private Request request;

public void onSenderReceiverChanged() {
   String senderNameValue = request.getParameter("param");
   Map<String, String> map = senderReceivers.getMap();

   if (map.get(senderNameValue) != null){
      currentDoc.setSenderReceiverAddress(map.get(senderNameValue));
      ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(srZone10);
   }
}
```

thanks in advance
Similar question: 
[cirylic text in tapestry grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012251/representation-of-cirylic-text-in-tapestry-grid)